# I have "Interrupted while waiting on semaphore" when I'm using ThreadManager and ChannelService in Google App Engine Javaservlet

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I want to send a message via `ChannelService.sendMessage` in a `ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest` runnable method. But I have an error message in jetty logger when I'm calling this method in doGet.
This is my code in HttpServlet class:

```
    @Override
public void  doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    name = req.getParameter("name");
    ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
                d = com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.DateTime.now();
                serverTime = String.valueOf(d.getMillis());
                ChannelMessage channelMessage = new ChannelMessage("logger", i+ " Message..... " + name + " Server Time: " + serverTime + " Client Time:");
                getChannelService().sendMessage(channelMessage);

            }

        }
    }).start();

}
```

And here is Error in jetty logger:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Interrupted while waiting on semaphore:
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:193)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:156)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:118)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:67)
at com.google.appengine.api.channel.ChannelServiceImpl.sendMessage(ChannelServiceImpl.java:85)
at com.roundtableapps.pluto.backend.MyServlet$1.run(MyServlet.java:42)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1$2.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:110)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.RequestThreadFactory$1$1.run(RequestThreadFactory.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1301)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl.makeAsyncCall(ApiProxyLocalImpl.java:190)
    ... 8 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest` thread will be stopped (interrupted) just after request. You have to wait there, unitil it finished, before exiting from `doGet` method.

So basically such thread doesn't make any sense. Also, you do all hard work (I mean loop block) in same thread, instead of parallelizing it.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void  doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    name = req.getParameter("name");
    List<Future> waits = new ArrayList<>(90);
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50, ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
       waits.add(executors.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
           Boolean call() { 
                d = com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.DateTime.now();
                serverTime = String.valueOf(d.getMillis());
                ChannelMessage channelMessage = new ChannelMessage("logger", i+ " Message..... " + name + " Server Time: " + serverTime + " Client Time:");
                getChannelService().sendMessage(channelMessage);
                return true;
            }

        }))
    }
    for (Future f: waits) {
       f.get()
    }

}
```

If you need only one thread, then all parts related to threading could be dropped off:

```
@Override
public void  doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {
    name = req.getParameter("name");
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
        d = com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.joda.time.DateTime.now();
        serverTime = String.valueOf(d.getMillis());
        ChannelMessage channelMessage = new ChannelMessage("logger", i+ " Message..... " + name + " Server Time: " + serverTime + " Client Time:");
        getChannelService().sendMessage(channelMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK! so, What is your solution for doing something in threads?

Comment: what is return value for your Call method?

Comment: anything, i guess it doesn't matter in your case

Comment: ok, It works. But I have a question. does `Executor.newFixedThreadPool` create 50 threads or more? because in this case I need only one thread.

Comment: 50. what the point of having one thread? for one thread your don't need to use ThreadManager, you already have current thread, just do everything in main thread, drop all code related to multithreading